# Spark SQL execution fails with error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Running a Spark SQL program in Java immediately fails with the following exception, as soon as the first action is called on a dataset. Have tried all the suggestions in [Spark SQL fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/commons/compiler/UncheckedCompileException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352091/spark-sql-fails-with-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-codehaus-commons-compil) nothing seems to work. Tried upgrading versions of Spark still facing the same error.

Please note not running using `spark-submit` but via `java -jar <app-name>`
Below is Spark Gradle config:

```
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12', version: '2.4.3'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:3.0.16'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.0.16'
```

Tried below exclusion config too, still same error persists:

```
    implementation('org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:2.4.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.janino', module: 'janino'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.janino', module: 'commons-compiler'
    }
    compile "org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:3.0.16"
    compile "org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.0.16"
```

Exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.JavaCode$.variable(javaCode.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.JavaCode$.isNullVariable(javaCode.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.$anonfun$genCode$3(Expression.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$Lambda$2984/0x00000000bfa2b020.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.genCode(Expression.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.$anonfun$create$1(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$$$Lambda$2982/0x00000000ef9c1620.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$Lambda$1442/0x00000000ff849e20.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.create(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.create(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsList$1(Dataset.scala:2794)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$Lambda$2827/0x00000000af983620.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$Lambda$2919/0x00000000cf9f4220.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$2920/0x00000000cfa4f020.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectAsList(Dataset.scala:2793)
```

Code implementation:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App demo").setMaster("local[*]");

try (SparkSession sparkSession = createSparkSession(sparkConf)) {
    Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().json("/Users/shubhampr/Documents/spark/examples/src/main/resources/people.json");
    df.show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error in processing file: {}", e.getMessage());
            return;
}

SparkSession createSparkSession(SparkConf sparkConf) {
        return SparkSession.builder()
                .sparkContext(new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf).sc())
                .getOrCreate();
}
```

Comment: You lack jars on your runtime classpath that were on your buildtime classpath.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I checked dependencies in runtime and build time classpath and they're similar.
Can you suggest any other issues?

Comment: How do you run your app? You submit or you connect directly? If you submit, share with us the command line.

Comment: @jgp I don't run it via spark-submit, it's generated at run-time will update code.

Answer (score 1):

We need to strict `janino:commons-compiler` to version `'3.0.16'`
Below is the fix which worked:

```
// Spark lib
    compile "org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:2.4.3"
    compile "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:2.4.3"
    implementation('org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler'){
        version {
            strictly '3.0.16'
        }
    }
    implementation('org.codehaus.janino:janino'){
        version {
            strictly '3.0.16'
        }
    }
```