# Apache Spark with Java Spring boot : Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, apache-spark

I'm trying to retrieve data from an Oracle Database table, and I'm new to Apache Spark.

I must retrieve data from two databases with two tables (production DB and lower environment)

must compare the data in both tables column by column and then insert it into another audit table in a lower environment. Later, a job will update the lower environment with the updated data.

Due to the enormous amount of data, many tables with various schemas will contain trillions of records.

The problem is that I cannot connect to and retrieve records from the database.

Any possible solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApacheSparkApplication.class, args);
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("SparkandOracledbTest").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> oracleDF = spark.read().format("oracle")
                .option("adbId", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/dbname")
                .option("dbtable", "owner.tablename")
                                .option("user", "user")
                                .option("password", "password")
                .load();
        oracleDF.show();

2022-10-26 08:25:22.557  INFO 5448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@244c93d7{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2022-10-26 08:25:22.765  WARN 5448 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState  : URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory failed to set FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory
2022-10-26 08:25:22.766  INFO 5448 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState  : Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
2022-10-26 08:25:22.776  INFO 5448 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState  : Warehouse path is 'file:/C:/Vijay/csv/spark-warehouse'.
2022-10-26 08:25:22.793  INFO 5448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7b364643{/SQL,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2022-10-26 08:25:22.794  INFO 5448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@76e99147{/SQL/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2022-10-26 08:25:22.795  INFO 5448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@40a15ec9{/SQL/execution,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2022-10-26 08:25:22.796  INFO 5448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@d385186{/SQL/execution/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2022-10-26 08:25:22.798  INFO 5448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3fa6b59a{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/janino/InternalCompilerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:675)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:725)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:171)
    at com.spark.csv.ApacheSparkApplication.main(ApacheSparkApplication.java:34)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 10 more
```

POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artif`actId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
       </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.janino/janino -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
       </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.janino/commons-compiler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.ojdbc/ojdbc8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Comment: I performed an operation to read a CSV file and write it to a text file to test the configuration for Apache-Spark, and it was successful. but with Oracle Database to read data it's not working.

Comment: Have yo tried without devtools? You also marked the `park-sql_2.13` dependency as provided which means it won't be shipped, you might want to change that.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Yes tried without devtools, but i didn't get on change for spark-sql_2.13 dependency.

Comment: The `spark-sql` dependency is scoped `provided`. Which means it isn't available in the fat jar you are building. If you are using classes from there they arent' available and you will get exceptions.

Comment: @M.Deinum, as i am doing simple with Sparksession i am not using any functions of spark-sql_2.13, even i tried without spark-sql_2.13, but the issue is same.

Comment: the package `org.apache.spark.sql` hints otherwise (but that might be my limited Spark knowledge). Looks like you are using an incompatible version of Janino (or spark). So you want to either up-/downgrade one of those to have compatible versions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352091/spark-sql-fails-with-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-codehaus-commons-compil